# Why do some developers randomize assets names in web pages

Tags: html, web, naming

When I'm surfing on Internet I do like to have a quick look at the code of at least one page before leaving websites I visit. But there's something I see often and ( that may be for security purpose but I want to be sure) is that the name of assets (js, css, and so on) can contain a randomized part.

This is an example in the source code of a page from GitHub:

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="https://assets-cdn.github.com/assets/frameworks-0d3df748b8f66933615db469504dcd2c686fccb2772bc4e7263abb77014b7bc3.css" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Can anyone explain the reason of that practice, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788200/why-the-names-of-some-css-js-files-have-random-numbers-in-them?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Github developer's can give the best answer of your question.

But in my opinion it may be the version name and encoded with any hashing technique so no one can see the actual name is.

It is best way to hide the originality to the users, bots, crawlers, etc.

May be they are handling logs of each version with its obfuscated name, because in the software world, there is need of history from version to version.

Even, I found some are using javascript `eval()` after the obfuscation compressed code/script so that no one can use their code directly by just copy and paste.